# Particles In Squarespace Background?

Tags: javascript, html, css, squarespace

I am a total noob when it comes to JS, but I have setup the particles library (https://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/) exactly as I'd like, and have even been able to get the JS to run in a div (like the Codepen), but I need to get it to run as the background of the Squarespace template.

```
https://sprout-heptagon-wjyy.squarespace.com/
Password: 1

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByClassName' of null
    at window.particlesJS (particles.min.js:9)
    at static1.squarespace.com/static/5d6ea3d4fa28060001ad957c/t/5d70439e59850f00013c7f6c/1567638430154/particle.js:7
```

I have tried several things:

1. I tried using JS to override the body's ID to `particles-js`, but this broke the squarespace template
2. I tried switching it to a class and adding the class to the body, but the particles library seems to not recognize it now.
3. I tried changing the JS to run off the default body class collection-5d6ea477c80c840001e6a6ad and the JS still hits an error

Codepen: https://codepen.io/Tollo/pen/YzKEqGm

I'd like to get the JS to run as the static background (preferably with Parallax scrolling) so that the user can always see the animation.

Comment: Based on the documentation for partical.js the first parameter to `particlesJS.load` is `dom-id` so a class name will not work.  Now I am not very familiar with Squarespace, but based on your first attempt, it sounds like there is a default ID on the body that that is used by Squarespace.  You should be able to update your CSS and JS code to use the Squarespace ID instead of "particles-js".  See this [fork](https://codepen.io/mminc10/pen/MWgrKMb) of your pen to see it work with an ID other than "particles-js".

Comment: I figured it out thanks to your comment! I ended up downloading the minified js file as well and hosting that... Once I did that and defered the script, I was able to load it no problem :)